# Getting Combinations of Unique Column

Tags: python, unique

I want to know if someone knows of a python function that returns a combination of columns without repetition. For example

```
a= [[1,2],
    [3,4]] 
# 1,4 is allowed since not the same column.
# 2,3 is allowed since not the same column.
# 1,3  is not allowed since its the same column.
# 2,4 is not allowed since its the same column.
```

Even if its a custom function you have made I would like to see it and understand the logic behind it.

Also if possible I want functions from modules readily available in python by default so don't want something like numpy where I have to manually install it via pip.

Thanks :)

Comment: seems like you need only one combination. for that you can generate random indexes and pull them. For eg `a[0][random(2)],a[1][random(2)]`

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: My actual input is a  square matrix  mat = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and exclude items in the same column after generating column indices using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
from itertools import product 

def prod(*args):
   for (i, x), (j, y) in product(*map(enumerate, args)):
      if i != j:
         yield (x, y)

a= [[1,2],
    [3,4]] 
print(list(prod(*a)))
# [(1, 4), (2, 3)]

a= [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]]
print(list(prod(*a)))
# [(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
```

You can generalize this for multiple rows and columns by checking that no column in each combination is repeated:

```
from itertools import product 

def prod(*args):
   for items in product(*map(enumerate, args)):
      if len({i for i, _ in items}) == len(items):
         yield tuple(x for _, x in items)
```

Comment: Your code works with my example but when I change input from my example to a square matrix  it fails. For example a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] can't scale it up.

Comment: @pyCharmer Updated my answer

Comment: Damn that's some beautiful code right there. Need to mess around with this so I can understand.

Comment: Could you please explain this line ,    len({i for i,_ in items}) and a bit more about the syntax about the if statement.

Comment: The builds a set from the column indices and checks that the length of the set is the same as the number of rows in the matrix. You can read about set comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

For larger square matrices, you could take use permutations of columns:

```
from itertools import *

b = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
    ]


def combs(mat=b):
    ncols = len(b[0])
    yield from ([mat[i][j] for i, j in inds]
            for inds in map(enumerate,
                permutations(range(ncols))))

# In [86]: list(q.combs()) 
# Out[86]: [[1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 7]]
```

Regarding the last line: given an `N x N` matrix, there are exactly `N!` ways to pick an element from each row without ever picking two or more from any column: You have `N` choices in the first row, `N-1` in the second, etc. Hence, each combination that meets your requirement is pinned down by a permutation. `map(enumerate, permutations(range(ncols)))` gives a list of all valid indexes. For a given index `inds`, `[mat[i][j] for i, j in inds]` gives a list corresponding to that index.

Comment: why the ugly `from itertools import *` though?

Comment: not sure why it's ugly, but true, you only need `permutations`.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on the yield from line. I don't  why this is the case. Also could you explain that line in a simple way.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports (see the last bullet). In summary, it i) pollutes the current namespace with all the unnecessary declarations from `itertools` ii) the code is less readable - you do not know where was which function defined

Comment: @pyCharmer `yield from` is available after Python 3.3. You can replace this with a for loop and then `yield`.

Comment: @RobinNemeth the standard makes sense but this is a matter of taste. I personally like the wildcard import from `itertools`, `operator` or `math` because there is little ambiguity and it makes interactive development faster. I'm sure a case can be made for either practice.